# How can I call a non-templated method instead of the templated one?

Tags: c++

I have two functions called writeLine(). I thought my line in main() would call the first writeLine(), but it calls the second writeLine(). How can I call the first writeLine() function? I'm just curious so I know later if it's possible or not. Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdarg>

void writeLine(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vprintf(format, args);
}

template <typename Key, typename Value>
void writeLine(const Key &key, const Value &value, const char *separator = " ")
{
    std::cout << key << separator << value << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    writeLine("%s is a test.", "This");

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output: "This is a test."

Current output: "%s is a test. This"

Comment: You want your template function to always fail overload resolution when `Key` is a `const char *`. Should be plenty of examples, somewhere around here, of doing this kind of thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could constrain the function-template to types that are not `char const *`,

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
std::enable_if_t<std::negation_v<std::is_same<std::decay_t<Key> , char *>>, void>
  writeLine(const Key &key, const Value &value, const char *separator = " ")
{
    std::cout << key << separator << value << std::endl;
}
```

so the non-template function is the only option.

Here's a working [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/455eEF)

Comment: This doesn't actually work. The reason it seems to work is since you wrote `std::negation<...>::type` instead of `::value` so substitution always fails. And fixing it doesn't work either, because `Key` is deduced as `char [N]`.

Comment: If it's not clear, here is an [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/j5vB6SVwHoWBAMT3).

Comment: yeah, you're right. It doesn't work. I posted without checking :(

Comment: @super I fixed it by `deay`ing `Key` first. Thanks a lot for pointing that out.

Comment: Nice, that's a clean solution.

Comment: No, if you add `const` it won't work. `decay` will remove the const. You can add a check for that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wonder, should 'char *' be 'const char *' in the constraint?

Answer (score 0):

You might read [overload_resolution#Best_viable_function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function):

> 1) there is at least one argument of F1 whose implicit conversion is better than the corresponding implicit conversion for that argument of F2

And later

> 2) A user-defined conversion sequence is always better than an ellipsis conversion sequence

- Template overload has exact match.
- C-ellipsis overload has ellipsis conversion.

Template overload is a best viable function.

You have to SFINAE the template function to discard it fromviable overload

```
template <typename Key, typename Value,
          std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<const char*, Key>, int> = 0>
void writeLine(const Key &key, const Value &value, const char *separator = " ")
{
    std::cout << key << separator << value << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to constrain the template as pointed out. When passing a string literal here it will be deduced as a const& to a char array, so we need to use `std::is_array` or make our own type trait to specifically target only char arrays.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdarg>

void writeLine(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vprintf(format, args);
}

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_char_array_v = false;

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr bool is_char_array_v<char[N]> = true;

template <typename Key, typename Value, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<Key, const char*>, int> = 0>
void writeLine(const Key &key, const Value &value, const char *separator = " ")
{
    std::cout << key << separator << value << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    writeLine("%s Hey", "This");

    return 0;
}
```